# How to count the number of occurrences of some symbols?

Tags: c#, string

In my program, you can write a string where you can write variables.

For example:

> The name of my dog is %x% and he has %y% years old.

The word where I can replace is any between `%%`. So I need to get a function where tells which variables I have in that string.

```
GetVariablesNames(string) => result { %x%, %y% }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx) to find anything that looks like a variable.

If your variables are percent-sign, any-word-character, percent-sign, then the following should work:

```
string input = "The name of my dog is %x% and he has %y% years old.";

// The Regex pattern: \w means "any word character", eq. to [A-Za-z0-9_]
// We use parenthesis to identify a "group" in the pattern.

string pattern = "%(\w)%";     // One-character variables
//string pattern ="%(\w+)%";  // one-or-more-character variables

// returns an IEnumerable
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches) { 
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
     var variableName = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

MSDN:

- [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've never used REGEX, can you provide a little help to determine the pattern?

Comment: Worth noting that if you allow variables of more than one character (ie %myvar%), the pattern changes to "%\w*%".

Comment: @Takkara thanks for pointing that out. I'd thought about it and forgot to add it.

Comment: Using the pattern `%(\w*)%` would also match zero-character variables, i.e. `%%`.

Comment: Gah... I'm rusty. Modified to use `+` which means one or more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to get the occurances, and group them to count the occurance for each one. Example:

```
string text = "The name of my dog is %x% and he has %y% years old.";

Dictionary<string, int> keys =
  Regex.Matches(text, @"%(\w+)%")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .GroupBy(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> key in keys) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0} occurs {1} time(s).", key.Key, key.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
x occurs 1 time(s).
y occurs 1 time(s).
```